# error while testing Windows 8 app made by the help of Construct 2

Tags: windows-8, construct-2

I was trying an empty project in Construct 2 and export it as Windows 8 app project and I'm getting this error:

[image]

Don't know what does it exactly mean and don't know what to do, a clue would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open "View local services" from the control panel (Cmd+W and type 'local service' for a shortcut) and start or restart the service called "Windows Firewall".